# rails how can I use parameter for updating record attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this spec method and I want to use address parameters to change @profile.website attribute

```
def should_validate_length_of(adress)
  @profile.adress = "x" * 393 
  @profile.save
end

should_validate_length_of('website')
```

But I encounter this `undefined method`adress='`

The solution should be easy but I dont know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
def should_validate_length_of(adress)
  @profile.update_attributes(address => ("x" * 393)) 
end

should_validate_length_of('website')
```